# Get src of image after clicking button

Tags: python, selenium

I've a python script (with selenium) where I can click a button:

```
button1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='test1']")
button1.click()
```

When I run the script, it opens chrome + my app and it clicks on the button.
After clicking on the button an image appears on the place of the button.

I can manually inspect this image:

```
<img style="" src="//files.qualifio.com/library/xxx.png" class="card_1">
```

Is there a way how I can get this `src` in Python after clicking my `button1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after clicking on button, introduce webDriver wait to wait till image loads in **DOM**.

```
img = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img.card_1')))  
source = img.get_attribute("src")  
print(source)
```

Note that, you will have to import :

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Cool it works! (although I had to remove the .wait)

Comment: @DenCowboy : Sorry , that's a  typo , I will remove it too.